# how to post plain json data to service stack rest service

Tags: servicestack

Below is the code  I am using to post json data to a rest ful service

var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);

```
        Todo d =  new Todo(){Content  = "Google",Order =1, Done = false };

        var s = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString < Todo>(d);

      //  client.Post<string>("/Todos/", "[{\"content\":\"YouTube\"}]");

     //   string payload= "[{\"id\":2,\"content\":\"abcdef\",\"order\":1,\"done\":false}]";
      //  string payload = @"{""todo"":{ {""content"":""abcdef"",""order"":1}} }";

        client.Post<string>("/todos/", s);
```

I tried passing plain json data , it keep on fialing with message "Bad data". Then i tried serizliing the entity that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PostJsonToUrl, which is included in ServiceStack.Text.